# How to Display Messagebox When No Values Found on SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, if-statement

Following is a code to get values from table in sql and set it to relevant fields. However i want to know how to write if condition in below block code so if the datatable contains the USERID it will performs function below but if it didn't find the USERID it should popup a error message saying no User Found.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand
("SELECT * From USER_TABLE WHERE USERID =" + userIdTextBox.Text, con1);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    nameTextBox.Text = (myReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString());
    lnameTextBox.Text = (myReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString());
    posTextBox.Text = (myReader["POSITION"].ToString());
    emailTextBox.Text = (myReader["E_MAIL"].ToString());
    phoneTextBox.Text = (myReader["PHONE"].ToString());
    usernameTextBox.Text = (myReader["USERNAME"].ToString());
    userLevelTextBox.Text = (myReader["USER_LEVEL"].ToString());
    string filename = (myReader["PROFILE_PICTURE"].ToString());
    profilePicBox.Load(filename);

}
```

Comment: Check [`If(myReader.HasRows)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If your query can only ever return a single user then change the WHILE into an IF and then add an ELSE clause to display the error message box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check [`if(myReader.HasRows)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  if(MyReader.HasRows)
    {
         while (myReader.Read())
                {
                   //your code here.
                }
    }
    else
    {
      // your alert.
    }
```

Comment: There's no need in additional check (`myReader.HasRows`): `myReader.Read()` returns true if any data has been read

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, MSDN states  _Read() returns true if there are more rows; otherwise false._ So if there is only one row it will return `false`?

Comment: No, it returns true: no records are read, and there's one that can be read. Read() will return false if there's no records to be read - on empty cursor only

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, you are right, check `if(MyReader.Read())` may be enough here. My answer will be more suitable if OP wants more than just one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (myReader.Read()) //assuming you only ever have a single result...
        {
            //set form fields.
        }
        else
        {
            //message box 
        }
```

**Edit** based on comment from **@dmitry-bychenko**

Comment: you can omit `myReader.HasRows` in the `if`